# Lucene: How to search for at least m out of n words

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

Suppose I have 5 words that I'm searching for. Is there a way to specify that the matching documents should have at least 4 of those words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a BooleanQuery, you can set the 'minimumShouldMatch' property. Here is the API link for more details: http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html#setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(int)